# Logout does not destroy/clear session properly in FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, session, garbage-collection

I'm having some problems, don't know why, when I logout from my application which is handled by FOSUserBundle since current session is never destroyed or even clear which is causing issues when I login back cause I store some data on session. This is how my `security.yml` looks like:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                default_target_path: home
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                 path: fos_user_security_logout
                 target: /
                 invalidate_session: false
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        ...
```

And this is how the `session` keys are configured at `config.yml`:

```
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id:  ~
    cookie_lifetime: 86400
    gc_maxlifetime: 600 # session will expire after 10 minutes of inactivity
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 1
```

I'm missing something else here?

As a second part of this question I have a big doubt since this is something new to me and it's related to how garbage collection works in Symfony2? I was reading [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#configuring-garbage-collection) around it but is not clear to me and also I don't know if this is the cause because session isn't destroyed properly when I logout from the application. Any explanation around this? If I'm not mistaken my application will logout users, automatically, when 10 min pass without do nothing, meaning **inactivity**, I'm right? But how or what the GC part do on this config? I take that configuration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21285238/719427) topic but not understand that one yet.

As an additional note, I'm working with Firefox|Chrome both in private windows so no cache from browser should exists.

Comment: I'm curious for a possible answer since I noticed this issue also in my logout from fosuserbundle.

Comment: What are the actual issues you are having?  You said issues with logout but it's not exactly clear what specifically you are experiencing.

Comment: Basically, the session of the user stays alive after logging out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`invalidate_session` option in [security.yml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) file is by default set to `true`, in your config its `false`, try to change it to `true`.

For clarification, here is the code from `SecurityExtension.php`

```
if (true === $firewall['logout']['invalidate_session'] && false === $firewall['stateless']) {
    $listener->addMethodCall('addHandler', array(new Reference('security.logout.handler.session')));
}
```

and `'security.logout.handler.session'`:

```
public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $request->getSession()->invalidate();
}
```

....

Comment: Apparently, that works, I'll accept your answer for now, since I need to do more test but if I have any problems I'll come back, thanks