# Symfony3 Update Users data and Invalidate current sessions

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-3.2

As I understand, When the user logs in successfully Symfony will keep a copy of the `User` document/entity either in the `session.handler.native_file` or a db provider, whichever is configured. On future requests this information is retrieved with the session id kept in the cookie.

My problem is whenever a user updates its password or username (which is their e-mail), previously opened sessions on different computers or browsers don't expire or as set as invalid.

The `EquatableInterface` is suppose to check against this but its not really working for me. As I added the following stub to the `User` class:

```
#User.php
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    return false;
}
```

Followed by a refresh on the browser nothing changed. My session was still valid and checking the `User` fetch with a `dump($this->getUser())` gave me the currently updated `User` and not the one was stored at the beginning of the session.

I tried using:

```
#security.yml
security:
    always_authenticate_before_granting: true
```

To if it would do anything, but it really didn't worked.

Using the *Symfony Profiler*, I see that a `User` is been fetch from the db every time I do a request and I wonder if it is at this point the the `UserProviderInterface` just updated the user in the `security.token_storage` instead of first checking against changes to end session if necessary.

To make sure this was happening I tested this controller on two different browsers:

```
#SomeController.php
public function indexAction()
{
    $encoder = $this->get('security.password_encoder');
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $flag = $encoder->isPasswordValid($user, 'MY_NEW_PASSWORD');

    dump($flag);

    return [];
}
```

I logged in to my application on both browsers, then logout on browser A. I changed the `User` password to `'MY_NEW_PASSWORD'` and just refresh browser B. The dump was `true` for the new password.

If this is the case I wonder:
- Is there anyway to make a check against the db before granting authorization when the `User` is been fetch from the `security.token_storage`? (It would be a service that is runs on the fetch event I guess.)

or maybe I'm over complicating stuff and there is a super simple solution that I just haven't figured out =|

Comment: have you already see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987089/invalidate-session-for-a-specific-user-in-symfony2 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805856/how-to-destroy-all-sessions-in-symfony-2 ?

Comment: Hello, I saw both solutions and none of them worked (pretty sure i made it clear in the question). After some testing I think it has something to do the mongodb user provider(?) as whenever I test the `isEqualTo() ` and the password changed it will return false, but the `UserProvider` will still refresh the user. Now I think I should make my own service to provide the user. When it calls `refreshUser()` and in the case the `isEqualTo()` return false, throw a `UnsupportedUserException` to prevent force it to end session.