# unwanted logout symfony 3.x FosUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, session-cookies, fosuserbundle

This is my `connfig/config.yml`

```
framework:   
    session:       
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

and this is my security configuration in `config/security.yml`

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

I use Symfony v3.1 and fos userbundle v2.0. My problem is that although I have not used any services for automatic logout users, a logged in user log out after 2 or 3 minutes. (this happens when user refresh page or submit a form or any thing that change rout)

I use `cookie_lifetime` in `config.yml` and increase cookie lifetime but still it logout very early.

`session.gc_maxlifetime` in my `php.ini` is set to 1440 means 24 minutes!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872721/how-to-log-users-off-automatically-after-a-period-of-inactivity