# Get current DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have a functioning site that includes a search function that loads results into a `<div>` element via a jQuery $.ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url:        '{{ path('order_search') }}',
    type:       $(this).attr('method'),
    data:       $('#search_form').serialize(),
    success:    function (data) {
        $('#js-search-results').html(data);
    }
});
```

I'm working in a twig template within a symfony project, thus the url notation. This is working perfectly.

This is on a site that requires login. I have an event listener in symfony that checks for a period of inactivity at each each kernel request (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872721/how-to-log-users-off-automatically-after-a-period-of-inactivity)), and if the inactive period exceeds a maxIdleTime then the user is redirected to the login page.

My problem is that if the user is inactive for a period and then enters a search, the `js-search-results` div is filled with the login page. What I would like to happen is to have the entire window redirect to the login page. Seems simple, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

One what I thought to handle would for my login page script to check whether it was being loaded into the full window (rather than just a div element), and if not then refresh the entire window. How to do this?

Comment: the back end code at `'{{ path('order_search') }}'` should return an error if the user isn't logged in, then the `$.ajax` should have an error handler to redirect the page to `login` in the case of an error - alternatively, the success function should check to see what `data` is, rather than blindly assuming it's a valid search response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the content inside the variable "*data*" to check if it contains elements from the login page and then use an if else statement.

```
if(data.includes("username") && data.includes("password")){
  window.location.assign("https://your.login.page.html");
}else{
  $('#js-search-results').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to find out what type of data is there and if it is the login page do a redirect.

Find out if the `data` contains elements that are in the login page. if it is do a `window.location.href = "/login"` if not display the search results in the div. send data from backend like {`page : "login"}`