# Symfony logout after inactivity, make log entry

Tags: php, symfony

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872721/how-to-log-users-off-automatically-after-a-period-of-inactivity) question

I have implemented an automatic logout of users after a certain period of inactivity (like in question above). This works fine, but I need to make a log entry for this event.

The problem is that when logout fires, I get multiple records in my log file instead of 1 record. I guess I need to listen to some other request, instead of `onKernelRequest`. Any ideas how to do that? My code is as follows:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CredentialsExpiredException;

class RequestListener{

protected $session;
protected $securityToken;
protected $router;
protected $logger;
protected $maxIdleTime;


public function __construct(Session $session, TokenStorage $securityToken, RouterInterface $router, $logger, $maxIdleTime)
{
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->securityToken = $securityToken;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->maxIdleTime = $maxIdleTime;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {

        return;
    }

    if ($this->maxIdleTime > 0) {
        $lapse = time() - $this->session->getMetadataBag()->getCreated();

        if ($lapse > $this->maxIdleTime) {
            $username = $this->securityToken->getToken()->getUser();
            if ($username !== 'anon.'){
                $username = $username->getUsername();
            }

            $this->securityToken->setToken(null);

            $this->session->getFlashBag()->set('error', 'Your session expired, you need to login again');
            $this->session->invalidate();
            $this->logger->makelog(//I get multiple log entries here instead of 1
                0,
                'Session timeout',
                $username
            );
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login')));
        }
    }
}
}
```

**UPD_1**

I have already created a logout listener, but it listens only for `logout` event when the `Logout` button is pressed and this action is logged with different log entry. In my code above I use `$this->session->invalidate()` in order to logout the user. My code for logout listener is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class LogoutListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface
{
protected $securityContext;
protected $entityManager;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(TokenStorage $securityContext, EntityManager $entityManager, $logger)
{
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function logout(Request $Request, Response $Response, TokenInterface $Token)
{
    $em = $this->entityManager;
    $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    $this->logger->makelog(1, 'Logout action, logout button', $user);
}
}
```

Comment: You'll want to create a custom `LogoutListener` that does what you want on a specific event (logging out, obviously). Good example of that can be found here: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/357/how-to-create-a-custom-logout-event-onlogout-listener-using-fosuserbundle-in-symfony-3

Comment: Thank you for response. I added an update for my question, pls see above

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Thanks!

Comment: yes, the problem was in cookie_lifetime param (in config.yml) and session_lifetime (in parameters.yml).  cookie_lifetime param should be significantly higher that session_lifetime