# How to redirect to login page after session timeout with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, security, session

My problem, When session timed out, i refresh the page and then i get 500 error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable.

because "id" is empty.

I want to redirect to login page, when user refreshes the page and his session has expired. How can I do it?

I falowed this [How to log users off automatically after a period of inactivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872721/how-to-log-users-off-automatically-after-a-period-of-inactivity)

I tried to use listener with Kernel action:

I modified TokenStorageInterface to AuthorizationChecker

Because this error:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
>   GE\CandidatBundle\EventListener\SessionIdleHandler::__construct() must
>   implement interface
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface,
>   instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker
>   given

```
<?php

namespace GE\CandidatBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

class SessionIdleHandler
{
    protected $session;
    protected $securityToken;
    protected $router;
    protected $maxIdleTime;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, AuthorizationChecker $securityToken, RouterInterface $router, $maxIdleTime = 0)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->securityToken = $securityToken;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->maxIdleTime = $maxIdleTime;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {

            return;
        }

        if ($this->maxIdleTime > 0) {

            $this->session->start();
            $lapse = time() - $this->session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed();

            if ($lapse > $this->maxIdleTime) {

                $this->securityToken->setToken(null);
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->set('info', 'You have been logged out due to inactivity.');

                // Change the route if you are not using FOSUserBundle.
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('fos_user_security_login')));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the services.yml:
I modified "@security.context" to "@security.authorization_checker"

Because the security.context service is deprecated.

```
my.handler.session_idle:
    class: GE\CandidatBundle\EventListener\SessionIdleHandler
    arguments: ["@session", "@security.authorization_checker", "@router", %session_max_idle_time%]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

In the parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    ...
    session_max_idle_time: 1800
```

Now when i refresh the page i get 500 error, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I have the same problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625363/how-do-i-redirect-to-my-sites-homepage-after-my-site-times-out).  Did you ever get an answer.  No one has ever responded to the two times that I've tried to get help with my question.

Comment: I found a reference on using firewall configuration to handle this at twpug.net/docs/Symfony2.pdf, starting on page 150. It says: ... the firewall can handle this (logout) automatically for you when you activate the logout config parameter: Once this is configured under your firewall, sending a user to /logout, will un-authenticate the current user. The user will then be sent to the homepage (the value defined by the target parameter). Both the path and target config parameters default to what’s specified here. Unfortunately, the actual details on how to do this were missing.