# How do I redirect to my site's homepage after my site times-out?

Tags: symfony-2.8

Without modifying the Symfony code, I want my site to automatically redirect the user to my site's homepage and display a message that the user's session has timed out.  Currently, when the time-out occurs the user's browser is automatically redirected to a confusing Symfony error that says:

Cannot redirect to an empty URL.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

Stack Trace
1. in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.php at line 76   -
    public function setTargetUrl($url)
    {
        if (empty($url)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cannot redirect to an empty URL.');
        }
        $this->targetUrl = $url;

2. at RedirectResponse ->setTargetUrl ('') in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.php at line 39
3. at RedirectResponse ->__construct ('', '302') in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 82
4. at Controller ->redirect ('') in src/AppBundle/Controller/BreakinOutBoardController.php at line 5436   +
5. at XXXXXXXController ->myVideosAction (null)
6. at call_user_func_array (array(object(XXXXXXXXController), 'myVideosAction'), array(null)) in
   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 142
7. at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1') in
   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 62
8. at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 67
9. at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) in
   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php at line 183
10. at Kernel ->handle (object(Request)) in web/app_dev.php at line 31

Logs   - 1 error

1. INFO - Matched route "app_breakinoutboard_myvideos".
2. INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
3. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
4. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
5. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
6. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
7. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
8. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
9. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
10. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
11. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
12. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
13. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
14. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
15. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
16. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
17. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
18. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
19. INFO - The "request" service is deprecated and will be removed in 3.0. Add a typehint for Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request to your controller parameters to retrieve the request instead.
20. INFO - The "request" service is deprecated and will be removed in 3.0. Add a typehint for Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request to your controller parameters to retrieve the request instead.
21. INFO - The "request" service is deprecated and will be removed in 3.0. Add a typehint for Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request to your controller parameters to retrieve the request instead.
22. CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Cannot redirect to an empty URL." at /var/www/vhosts/symfony2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.php line 76
23. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
24. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
25. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
26. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
27. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
28. DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".

Comment: Note, if I refresh the error page that Symfony2 displays. my homepage is displayed with the timeout message.  So the question is how to do this without displaying the error page?

Comment: I found a reference on using firewall configuration to handle this at http://twpug.net/docs/Symfony2.pdf, starting on page 150. It says: ... the firewall can handle this (logout) automatically for you when you activate the logout config parameter: Once this is configured under your firewall, sending a user to /logout, will un-authenticate the current user. The user will then be sent to the homepage (the value defined by the target parameter). Both the path and target config parameters default to what’s specified here.  However, the details on how to do this were missing.